# Ant exec task: How to break one long argument into multiple lines

Tags: ant

In my Ant skript, i'm executing a program, passing some arguments, of which one is a very long argument:

```
<exec executable="${conf.GLASSFISH}/bin/asadmin" failonerror="true" vmlauncher="false">
  <arg line="create-auth-realm" />
  <arg line="--classname com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm" />
  <arg line="--property jaas-context=${conf.auth.jaas-context}:datasource-jndi=${conf.auth.datasource-jndi}:user-table=${conf.auth.usertable}:user-name-column=${conf.auth.usernamecolumn}:password-column=${conf.auth.passwordcolumn}:group-table=${conf.auth.grouptable}:group-name-column=${conf.auth.groupnamecolumn}:assign-groups=${conf.auth.assigngroups}:digest-algorithm=${conf.auth.digest}" />
  <arg line="jdbcRealm" />
</exec>
```

How can i split the 3rd argument into multiple lines, so the ant-skript is more readable (lower line width)? Something like this (\ is just a placeholder to demonstrate what i need):

```
<exec executable="command">
  <arg line="--property PROP1:\\"/>
  <arg line="PROP2:\\"/>
  <arg line="PROP3\\"/>
</exec>
```

So when Ant executes this it should result in the following command:

```
command --property PROP1:PROP2:PROP3
```

How can i realize that?

Answer (score 5):

`arg line` is deprecated in Ant.  Use `arg value` instead.  See this example from the docs.  If you do this, the world will be a happier and safer place.

```
<target name="help">
  <exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="ant.bat"/>
    <arg value="-p"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: That way, each parameter is seperated from the previous one with a space. I don't want that. All parameters of the executable should be concatenated as ONE string. I still didn't find a possibility to do that.

Comment: value will pass even an empty argument to an executable, line will not. This may or may not be desirable. For example, adb '' shell is not understood by the fickle adb tool. Hence the Android build.xml uses line for "${adb.device.arg}".

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: this is good to know, but it does not help and seems very unrelated to the question => should be a comment instead

Comment: Not sure if `<arg line="..">` was deprecated back in 2010 but it [certainly is not now](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg). Maybe you referred to passing command line params to `<exec command="">` which is indeed deprecated in favor of `<exec executable="..">` with nested `<arg>` elements as explained in bold [in the `exec` Parameter docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
  <path id="exec.parms" >
    <pathelement  path="PROP1:" />
    <pathelement  path="PROP2:" />
  </path>
```

And then use it in the exec:

```
<arg pathref="exec.parms" />
```

You can use the prefix attribute with value "--property " in arg to create the following:

```
--property PROP1:
--property PROP2:
```

Comment: Hmm when i do it that way, Ant appends my home directory to the pathref, resulting in the following argument: /home/mackaz/arg1:/home/mackaz/arg2 but i want an argument like arg1:arg2

Comment: neither `<arg path="${cp}" />` nor `<arg pathref="cpref" />` work for me here if the line itself is too long to be "digested" :-( (ant 1.9.4): *"[exec] Die Befehlszeile ist zu lang." (command line is too long)*